# Windows cannot find 'C:\Windows\System32\OptionalFeatures.exe'. error while clicking Turn Windows feature on or off in control panel

Tags: windows, windows-10, iis

I need to access an FTP site and want to setup IIS, but when clicking *Turn Windows feature on or off* in Control Panel, I receive error:

```
Windows cannot find C:\Windows\System32\OptionalFeatures.exe
```

[image]

- I have tried `sfc /scannow`, but it is also showing:

  ```
  sfc /scannow is not recognized as an internal or external command
  ```
- I cannot do anything from Registry Editor and have also set `PATH` in Environment variable:

  ```
  C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Users\Akshay\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;C:\Users\Akshay\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
  ```

Can anyone point me in a better direction?

Comment: Add to your post the contents of your PATH variable.

Comment: ok Added in my post

Comment: The PATH seems ok. Does the file `C:\Windows\System32\OptionalFeatures.exe` exist?

Comment: No it doesn't exist, how do i get that?

Comment: @AkshayMakwana Are those the User environment `PATH` or the System `PATH`?

Comment: The Path is of System Variables @JW0914

Answer (score 0):

Windows components are missing, which is strange and worrying.

If it was not you that deleted these files, it could have been either
a faulty antivirus that you have installed, or your computer is
infected.

I suggest starting with taking backups of your data.

Then
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)
in order to restore Windows to a working state.
This is equivalent to doing a major Windows upgrade.

If Windows is now working, do deep antivirus scans with several
well-known antivirus products. If any of them find anything,
you will find more information in the post
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

The last option is formatting your disk and installing Windows from
scratch, but let's hope that you can avoid it.

Comment: OK thanks, I will follow these